# Handling alternate spellings of a personal name

Tags: etiquette, personal-name

Dealing with a text that mentions several times the architectural historian Siegfried Giedion. A number of Giedion's books feature his first name as "Sigfried" and others as "Siegfried." Where is guidance in the *Chicago Manual of Style* on how to handle this in indexing his name and in any footnotes where he and/or his works are to be mentioned?

Should it simply be "Siegfried/Sigfried Giedion" in every single case or just in the index (Giedion, Siegfried/Sigfried)? Giedion was published by highly reputable presses under both names.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate spellings.  In indexing, you can add an extra line to the references:

> *Tchebyscheff*, see *Chebyshev*

Sometimes I see an alternative in brackets:

> Pafnuty Lvovich Chebyshev [Пафну́тий Льво́вич Чебышёв]